# Pass filter to retriever dinamically in LangChain

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I have a few Pinecone retrievers:

```py
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Pinecone

index_name = "example"
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(
        index_name=index_name, embedding=embeddings
    )

retriever_exclu=docsearch.as_retriever(
    max_tokens_limit=4097,
    search_kwargs={
        'k': 3,
        'filter': {
            'market_code': 'EXCLUSIF'}}).configurable_fields(
            search_kwargs=ConfigurableField(
                id="retrieve_exclu_kwargs",
                name="EXCLU Retrieve Search"))

retriever_best=docsearch.as_retriever(
    max_tokens_limit=4097,
    search_kwargs={
        'k': 3,
        'filter': {
            'market_code': 'BEST'}}).configurable_fields(
            search_kwargs=ConfigurableField(
                id="retrieve_best_kwargs",
                name="BEST Retrieve Search"))
```

and a RunnableParallel that runs them:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda, RunnablePassthrough, RunnableParallel

# Retrieval
retrieve_product = RunnableParallel({
    "products_best": itemgetter("question") | retriever_best,
    "products_exclu": itemgetter("question") | retriever_exclu
}).with_config({"run_name": "RetrieveProducts"})
```

Finally, I have a chain that runs that RunnableParallel, after an LLM call.

```py
recommand_chain = (
    RunnableParallel(
    {
        "need": generate_need,
        "question": itemgetter("question")
    }) |
    RunnableParallel(
    {
        "need": itemgetter("need"),
        "products": retrieve_product | RunnableLambda(filter_product),
        "question": itemgetter("question")
    }).with_config({"run_name": "1: Need & Retrieve"})
)
```

I'd like to take a specific component of the results of the first LLM call, and use it as a filter for those retrievers.
How can I update the 'filter' element from `search_kwargs`, inside the chain?
Something like this:

```
recommand_chain = (
    RunnableParallel(
    {
        "need": generate_need,
        "nature": itemgetter("need").get("nature")
        "question": itemgetter("question")
    }) |
    RunnableParallel(
    {
        "need": itemgetter("need"),
        ,
        "products": retrieve_product(filter.add_condition("nature":itemgetter("nature"))),
        "question": itemgetter("question")
    }).with_config({"run_name": "1: Need & Retrieve"})
)
```